# Dropwizard json null value: @JsonInclude not working

Tags: java, json, jackson, dropwizard

i am having an issue where i receive a json null value:

**"promo":null**

that throws an error

**! java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String**

weird thing is that i specified promo as a String in my POJO as follows

**String promo;**

Not sure why it is giving NUmberFormatException

i tried adding

**@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)**

or

**@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)**

as well

**environment.getObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);**

or

**environment.getObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);**

without any results.

I also wrapped

**groupPOJO = gson.fromJson(payload, GroupPOJO.class);**

with try-catch to see if that solves it, and nothing.

i am using jackson 2.6.3

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: is `promo` the only field in your POJO?

Comment: @kgdinesh. Thank you. No it is not. It goes something like this:                                                          `....."comps_value":"$100",
 "promo":null,
 "sent_Table_name":"A1",......`

Comment: can you kindly add the complete POJO along with the stack trace of the exception you got in the question?

Comment: When you map json to an object you will always have NULL for all values not present in the payload, if that is the problem you are having.